# C# console app always rebuilds, but I've already traced diagnostic build output

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, rebuild

I've looked at more pages than I can count about how to solve the "I didn't change anything, so why is VS rebuilding my project" problem. And they were helpful for resolving a number of issues with "copy always" flags, and custom build steps that always run. But I'm left with one that won't go away. It passes all the up-to-date fast dependency checks, but continues to start the build anyway. I've traced through all the MSBuild output at the diagnostic level, but I think the "normal" (not minimal) level is sufficient to point in the right direction. Here's the output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: OnePawDataSerializer, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Build started 12/20/2019 5:04:37 PM.
1>GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
1>Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>CoreCompile:
1>Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
1>  Touching "D:\Volpe\NuCS-HiEx\NuCS-Repo\Applications\FAB4DA\OnePawDataSerializer\obj\x64\Debug\OnePawDataSerializer.csproj.CopyComplete".
1>_CopyAppConfigFile:
1>Skipping target "_CopyAppConfigFile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
1>CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
1>  OnePawDataSerializer-> D:\Volpe\NuCS-HiEx\NuCS-Repo\Applications\FAB4DA\bin\Debug64\OnePawDataSerializer.exe
1>
1>Build succeeded.
1>    0 Warning(s)
1>    0 Error(s)
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.20
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 15 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

At this level of output verbosity it doesn't show all the stuff that looks like this:

```
1>------ Up-To-Date check: Project: CommonDataModelUtilities, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>All outputs are up-to-date.
1>Time Elapsed 19 ms
```

But they all indicate that everything is up to date. In the "normal"-level output, it shows a couple of internal targets being skipped, but then seems to need to execute one called "`_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal`", which doesn't seem to actually copy anything, but does appear to create a file with the name of the project file appended by ".CopyComplete". This appears to be the only instance of the build actually "doing" something tangible, so I'm inclined to suspect that this has something to do  with why I'm not seeing this:
`========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 16 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========`
when I build. But I can't figure out *why* it's doing it. Any thoughts?

Comment: hi chris, did you have any luck resolving this? i'm having the same problem.

Comment: Other people on the project performed a migration to VS2019 which coincided with several architectural changes. The upshot is that the problem is no longer there, but I didn't do anything to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

> This appears to be the only instance of the build actually "doing"
>   something tangible, so I'm inclined to suspect that this has something
>   to do with why I'm not seeing this: ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0
>   failed, 16 up-to-date, 0 skipped ========== when I build. But I can't
>   figure out why it's doing it. Any thoughts?

MSBuild uses incremental compilation, which only compiles files that have been modified, and skips building for files that have not changed. So when build your project again without any changes, it will like this as you wish:

```
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 16 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

This is the normal behavior generated by MSBuild.

**But** if you build your project again without changing any project files and build always execute, l am afraid that the issue is caused by some project files' settings(set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy Always`). (Or you can see the files in the xxx.csproj file and then you will find some files add the node  `<CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>`)

[image]

According to the build log info from your picture, the targets `_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal` and `CopyFilesToOutputDirectory` are responsible for copying project resources which you specify as the picture shows to the output path. And when you set the file to **Copy Always**, MSBuild will always consider this operation to be up to date, so it will always execute.

**Note**: Build is the process by which msbuild executes a bunch of target targets which contains the compile target. If the files are already compiled and they are not changed, the target will skip. Besides, if some projects are not changed, MSBuild will skip compiling them and regard them as **up - to - date**.

To prove it l have do a test:

1) I set the project file called JavaScript1.js to `Copy Always` as the picture shows above.

2) Then when I build the project multiple times, it always turns that the build executes successfully.

[image]

**In addition**, if you want this behavior, you could set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Do not copy`. Or if you want to output these files, you can set to `Copy if newer`.

**Update1**

If cannot see this abnormal behavior directly, l think you can set `MSBuild project build output verbosity` to `Diagnostic`.This mode will display every detailed info about build process.

And l have observed that the build log only shows two targets which are 
running `_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal` and `CopyFilesToOutputDirectory`.

So please check the target `CopyFilesToOutputDirectory`, _CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal, `Copy` task in the Diagnostic build log by the search box and you can search any detailed info about this.

[image]

**And in my side**, l can see this info in the first line of build output which is explain why my project always rebuild:

```
Project 'ConsoleApp1' is not up to date. Project item 'C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\ConsoleApp32\ConsoleApp32\JavaScript1.js' has 'Copy to Output Directory' attribute set to 'Copy always'.
```

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help me, as I already indicated in the question that I was already aware of, and thus eliminated, any instances of "Copy Always", and yet the problem persists. But thanks for responding.

Comment: `_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal` is mainly responsible for building the reference DLL which set `Copy Local` to `True` (properties window of the DLL --> copy local). Besides, if necessary, sharing the current project's xxx.proj is a better choice to troubleshoot your issue.Thanks!

Comment: And l wonder if your current project has any reference project which has some `copy always` or any other operation. So please check any possible files. Besides,from the picture, the project `OnePawDataSerializer` always builds. Due to it, the project could have some special operation.Please check the `OnePawDataSerializer.csproj` file which l think has some special steps and you can share with us by github or onedrive so that it will help us troubleshoot your issue.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Perry. There are referenced dependent projects, but as you can see from the output above, they don't get mentioned in the subsequent build, only in the initial build. So they cannot be the culprit. Also, I went through the diagnostic build output pretty thoroughly before posting. The diagnostic output shows all the dependent projects being skipped because they're up to date. And there are no pre-build or post-build events associated with the project.

Comment: In my References section  for the project, two of the dependent projects' properties screens have "Copy Local" set to true, however I've read warnings against setting this to false. except for things that you already expect to exist on the deployment machine. Since the projects in question are build dependencies, they're part of this code base and not something like "System.Core" which I expect to be on the target machine. So Copy Local = true makes sense. And I don't see why that should invalidate the build and cause it to build again next time.

Comment: Also, the word "always" does not appear anywhere in the .csproj file.

Comment: Due to your description, it is not related to  file with `Copy Always`, you could  try [this document](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/documentation/wiki/Rebuilding-when-nothing-changed.md) to troubleshot your issue.

Comment: Thanks, Perry. I appreciate the link and the time you spend looking at this and offering suggestions.